# base64 to PDF in ReactJS using API call

Tags: javascript, adobe

i am struggling to display the PDF in the browser, although i am getting Base64 code and using onlinetool(https://base64.guru/converter/decode/pdf) i can see the code convert into the correct PDF file that is stored in the backed.
After that i convert to blob Object and then it doesnt seems to open in the adobe reader when i click on the button.

```
// when the button is pressed, it will call the API to get the PDF document 

 const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("content-type", "application/json");
        headers.append("responseType", "arraybuffer");

        const options = {
          method: "POST",
          headers,
          credentials: "include",
          body: JSON.stringify(invoice_Object),
          // body: "My HTML String",
        };

        const newRequest = new Request("http://localhost:5000/api/invoice-only", options);

        (async () => {
          const invoice_Call = await fetch(newRequest)
            .then((res) => {
              return text1 = res.text();
            })
            .then((data) => {
             generateFile(data, invoice_Name);// here data is the actual item that i am looking to display as PDF document
            });
        })();
      };
```

- Then it will open the PDF document in adobe reader, here the console `content`  shows the correct Base64 code i think as seen when i use the code on online tool to convert to PDF document.
  So i am not sure if i am doing something wrong here generating the blob object and display as pdf.

```
   let generateFile = (content, fileName) => {
       console.log("content", content); // here at console if i copy the code and use online tool(https://base64.guru/converter/decode/pdf) it shows the correct pdf
       const blob = new Blob([content], { type: "application/pdf" });
       console.log(blob);
       const link = document.createElement("a");
       link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
       link.download = fileName;
       link.click();
       };
```

- **Backend code**

```
     fs.readFile(`${__dirname}\\` + `${Invoice_No_Actual}` + `.pdf`, (err, data) => {
          if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
          else {
                   res.contentType("application/pdf");
                 res.send(`data:application/pdf;base64,${new Buffer.from(data).toString("base64")}`);
          }
        });
      }
```

- BI have also `uploaded` the `base64 code` that i am getting when console logging at pastebin, https://pastebin.com/W4zEXyPy
- Error when opening the PDF document after i click the button

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response type needs to be `arraybuffer` in order to create a blob out of it. Keep the content type of the blob as it is (application/pdf):

```
const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("content-type", "application/json");
    headers.append("responseType", "arraybuffer");
```

Edit: Please see my comments down below, it seems like you are parsing invalid base64

Comment: Thanks Feddy, i have changed the response type but it seems to have the same issue, i have added the server side config as well above if that helps. thanks alot

Comment: @Umair_007 Can you please try changing the content type on your server side now as well (to arraybuffer)? Both places - when you set it and when you send it

Comment: @Umair_007 Actually I think all you have to do is separate your main base64 code from the rest of the response (content type and the "base64," string). There are many ways to do that but I would suggest changing your response to json eveywhere, and return the content type and base64 as keys. Then on the front end, in the part where you do "res.text();", you will need to only get the base64. Something like return "text1 = JSON.parse(res.base64)"

Comment: And by all that I mean that when you create the file, you should use "JVBERi0xLjQKMSAwIG9iago8PAovVGl0...." instead of "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKMSAwIG9iago8PAovVGl0....."

Comment: Thanks Feddy, i have tried to to change response to JSON and then when i do json.parse or res.json it comes up error with the token  error. maybe i am doing not the correct way. i am still a bit new with all this. would you give me some example code if possible.

Comment: @ feddy, hey mate, i have used content.slice(29); so it will start from JVB...(rather from data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xL........) but getting the same error.. wonder what else i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

you can convert the base64 to blob

Easiest way, use the Fetch API to convert base64 to blob.

here's the code...

```
    const pdfstr = await fetch(pdf);   \\pdf is the base64 string
    const blobFromFetch= await pdfstr.blob();

  
    var blob = new Blob([blobFromFetch], {type: "application/pdf"});
    
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  

  window.open(blobUrl,"_blank");
```

hope it helps!